# How to change normal table border to image border of table?

Tags: html, css

How to change normal table border to image border of table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to change normal table border to
>   image border of table?

I *think* you are referring to `border-image` property of CSS3. Check out this tutorial for more info:

http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/